# Deleting element from linked list in C

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, function-definition

I am trying to write a function, which is deleting a specific element from my linked list, but it crash with segmentation fault when I reach the element.
Here is a part of my code

```
typedef struct dlist_t {
    int data;
    struct dlist_t *prev, *next;
} dlist_t;

typedef struct list_t {
    dlist_t *head, *tail;
} list_t;

int delElement(list_t *list, int elem) {
    while (list) {
        if ((list->head)->data == elem) {
            list->head->next = list->head->prev;
            list->head->prev = list->head->next;
            free(list);
            return 1;
        }
        list = list->head->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems the code does not make sense. Show the list definition.

Comment: Draw it out for yourself in a diagram. By the way, this is incomplete code. We don't know what the struct looks like (although we may have a good idea) and we don't know how you allocated the memory you are freeing here and how you populated the linked list. And you probably typedef'ed the struct (which you should not do because it does not help in any way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function definition does not make sense. For example in this assignment statement

```
list = list->head->next;
```

there are used objects of different types in the left hand side of the assignment (the type is `list_t`) and in the right hand side of the assignment (the type is `dlist_t`).

Or this call

```
free(list);
```

tries to free the list instead of only its one node. And so on.

The function can look the following way as it is shown in thje demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct dlist_t 
{
    int data;
    struct dlist_t *prev, *next;
} dlist_t;

typedef struct list_t 
{
    dlist_t *head, *tail;
} list_t;

int delElement( list_t* list, int elem )
{
    dlist_t **current = &list->head;

    while ( *current != NULL && ( *current )->data != elem )
    {
        current = &( *current )->next;
    }

    int success = *current != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        dlist_t *tmp = *current;

        if ( ( *current )->next != NULL )
        {
            ( *current )->next->prev  = ( *current )->prev;
        }
        else
        {
            list->tail = ( *current )->prev;
        }

        *current = ( *current )->next; 

        free( tmp );
    }

    return success;
}

int pushFront( list_t *list, int elem )
{
    dlist_t *new_node = malloc( sizeof( dlist_t ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->next = list->head;
        new_node->prev = NULL;
        new_node->data = elem;

        if ( list->head != NULL )
        {
            list->head->prev = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            list->tail = new_node;
        }

        list->head = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}

int pushBack( list_t *list, int elem )
{
    dlist_t *new_node = malloc( sizeof( dlist_t ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->prev = list->tail;
        new_node->next = NULL;
        new_node->data = elem;

        if ( list->tail != NULL )
        {
            list->tail->next = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            list->head = new_node;
        }

        list->tail = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}

void printList( list_t *list )
{
    for ( dlist_t *current = list->head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", current->data );
    }

    puts( "null" );
}


void printReverseList( list_t *list )
{
    for ( dlist_t *current = list->tail; current != NULL; current = current->prev )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", current->data );
    }

    puts( "null" );
}

int main(void) 
{
    list_t list = { .head = NULL, .tail = NULL };

    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if ( i % 2 == 0 ) pushFront( &list, N / 2 - i / 2 - 1 );
        else pushBack( &list, N / 2 + i / 2 );
    }

    printList( &list );
    printReverseList( &list );

    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if ( i % 2 == 0 ) delElement( &list, i / 2 );
        else delElement( &list, N - i / 2 - 1 );

        printList( &list );
        printReverseList( &list );

        putchar( '\n' );
    }       

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 -> null

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> null

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> null
8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> null

2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> null
8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> null

2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> null
7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> null

3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> null
7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> null

3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> null
6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> null

4 -> 5 -> 6 -> null
6 -> 5 -> 4 -> null

4 -> 5 -> null
5 -> 4 -> null

5 -> null
5 -> null

null
null
```

Play with the program and playing investigate it.

Do not forget to write yourself the function that frees all allocated nodes in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Im not too sure what causes your crash yet, but here i have a sample of code that should work.
Struct definition:

```
typedef int item_type;
typedef struct _list* list;

struct node {

    item_type data;
    struct node *next,*prev;

};

struct _list {

    struct node* head;
    struct node* tail;
    int size;
};
```

Function for "element" deletion

```
void list_del(list l,item_type data) {

    if (list->size ==0) {
        abort();
    }

    int i=0;
    struct node* head = l->head;

    while(i<list->size){
        if(head->data==data){
            head->prev = head->next;
            l->size -= 1;
            free(head);
            return;
        }else{
            head=head->next;
        }
    }

}
```

"item_type" it's a typedef, if you have lots of functions and you shouldn't care much about types. In our example is as you wanted type int

Answer (score -1):

don't worry just try this code out.This is simplest of implementation and deletion a node in linked list and still if you face any issue feel free to ask .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
   int data;
   struct Node *next;
}*first=NULL;

void create(int A[],int n)
{
   int i;
   struct Node *t,*last;
   first=(struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
   first->data=A[0];
   first->next=NULL;
   last=first;

 for(i=1;i<n;i++)

 {
   t=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
   t->data=A[i];
   t->next=NULL;
   last->next=t;
   last=t;
 }

}

void Display(struct Node *p)
{
   while(p!=NULL)
   {
      printf("%d ",p->data);
      p=p->next;
   }
}

void RDisplay(struct Node *p)

{
  if(p!=NULL)
  {
      RDisplay(p->next);
      printf("%d ",p->data);

  }
}

int Delete(struct Node *p,int index)
{
   struct Node *q=NULL;
   int x=-1,i;

 if(index < 1 || index > count(p))
 return -1;

 if(index==1)
 {
    q=first;
    x=first->data;
    first=first->next;
    free(q);
    return x;
 }

 else
 {
   for(i=0;i<index-1;i++)
   {
       q=p;
       p=p->next;
   }
   q->next=p->next;
   x=p->data;
   free(p);
   return x;

 }


}

int main()
{

    int A[]={10,20,30,40,50};
    create(A,5);

    printf(“%d\n",Delete(first),2);
    Display(first);

    return 0;
}
```

So first we have created the linked list using *malloc* function . We have created a structure with variable which will build linked list i.e *"data"* and also created the *pointer* of *struct* type .

Then we have created a function name "create" to create our first node .And inserted the value according to it .

Then as you can see we g=have used for loop to fasten the process of creating the link list till the value of n.

Then for displaying the linked list we have created the function name *"Display"*
and if *p!=NULL* i.e node last column which contain address we have print the values/data of that node using for loop.

Then for deletion we have used function name *"Delete"* :

**1st step**: Is we need a pointer "p" that will point on first node .

**2nd step**: Now move first to next node.

**3rd step**: Now store the value of deleted node in new variable "x".

**4th step**: Delete p

The remaining code is for deleting the node from the specific position by using the two pointer, *one pointer for previous node and next pointer for current node*.

Just try this out or cross check with your code where you are going wrong .

Comment: Your code is badly misindented.  It sets a bad example for other readers and makes it hard to read. Furthermore, you use a very different representation of linked lists, so the code is not pertinent to the OP. Dumping code without an explanation is not really helpful.

Comment: I am really sorry for this, this won't be happening next time i will take care of this and i will edit it and will try to post it more clearly.

Comment: I have edited the code please do check still if you have doubt you can ask .

Comment: I am sorry, but your code is still indented inconsistently. For example in `Delete`, the `if` statement is less indented than the local variable definitions preceding it. C code can be tricky, there are already too many places where bugs can hide in plain sight, proper presentation is a must to make readable code where software defects are easier to spot. Furthermore, your simple linked list is not what the OP is asking about: the structures in the question document a doubly linked list with a `head` and `tail` outer shell. Updating that is more complicated than your example.